# How do I change type variables in OCaml?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

Assuming we've got the following type and type variable:

```
type example_type = A | B | C of example_type * example_type * example_type
let ab = C(A, C(A, B))
```

How can I manage to output a modification or a modified copy of ab? 
For example the following should be fulfilled:
 `val ab : example_type = C(A, C(A, A))` or `val new_ab : example_type = C(A, C(A, A))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values of the type `example_type` are immutable. And variables in OCaml (like `ab`) are also immutable. So you can't change the value that `ab` is bound to, or change the internals of the value itself.

In functional programming, you calculate new values rather than modifying old ones.

For what it's worth, your example value isn't valid for your `example_type` as declared. The `C` constructor takes 3 values, but you have only 2.

Also, `ab` is just a variable, not a type variable. It's a name bound to a value of type `example_type`.

Here is a function that eliminates all the `B`s from a value of type `example_type`. It replaces them with `A` instead.

```
let rec replace_b x =
    match x with
    | B -> A
    | A -> A
    | C (p, q, r) ->
        C (replace_b p, replace_b q, replace_b r)
```

Note that this function doesn't modify its parameter `x`. It constructs a new value.

Comment: Oh the `C` constructor should obvioulsy be `example_type * example_type`. <br> Thank you for the example :)

Comment: Obvious to you, perhaps :-)